# How to return a list of multiple JSON items in java, part 2

Tags: java, json, ldap

This question is a follow up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63256209/how-to-return-a-list-of-multiple-json-items-in-java) .

Again, I am completely new to Java and JSON, so I don't know much at all. I was able to proceed a little further with the answers from the question mentioned above, but now I have encountered more issues, namely (basically) the syntax of how to return the list of multiple JSON. (I got these codes from SpringBoot, and I really don't know how it all works; I am still learning Java.)

Currently, this is what I've tried:

```
@GetMapping("reports/{userID}")
public ResponseEntity<LookupResponseList> getDirectReports(@PathVariable String userID) {
    Optional<List<LDAPModel>> ldapModel = ldapService.getDirectReports(userID);
        if (!ldapModel.isPresent()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        LookupResponseResultList result = ldapMapper.toLookupResponseResultList(ldapModel.get());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(LookupResponseList.result(result, LookupResponseList.class));
    }
```

But I don't know how to return the list in the code above, on the line where I am trying to get the result:

```
LookupResponseResultList result = ldapMapper.toLookupResponseResultList(ldapModel.get());
```

The code for ldapMapper.toLookupResponseResultList is below:

```
   public LookupResponseResultList toLookupResponseResultList(List<LDAPModel> ldapModel) {
        return LookupResponseResultList.builder()
                .userId(ldapModel.toString())
//                .userId(ldapModel.getUserId())
//                .telephoneNumber(ldapModel.getTelephoneNumber())
                .build();
    }
```

The two commented line is what I want. I can see the entire JSON structure in the line above the commentted line, which is this:

```
{
    "result": {
    "userId": "[LDAPModel(userId=abcde123,telephoneNumber=1-555-5555555), LDAPModel(userId=fghi456,telephoneNumber=1-333-3333333)]",
    },
    "error": null
}
```

How can I make it so that toLookupResponseResultList return a list of multiple JSON (like below) instead of a string?

```
{
"result": [
    {
      "userId": "abcde123",
      "telephoneNumber": "1-555-5555555"
    },
    {
      "userId": "fghi456",
      "telephoneNumber": "1-333-3333333"
    }
    ],
"error": null
```

}

Edit: LookupResponseResultList class is below:

```
public class LookupResponseList extends BaseBodyResponse<LookupResponseList.LookupResponseResultList> {
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public static class LookupResponseResultList {
    String userId;
    String telephoneNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is at -

```
   public LookupResponseResultList toLookupResponseResultList(List<LDAPModel> ldapModel) {
    return LookupResponseResultList.builder()
            .userId(ldapModel.toString()) // THIS LINE
            .build();
}
```

This LookupResponseResultList class must accept a List of LDAPModel objects.

```
class LookupResponseResultList {
    @JsonProperty
    private List<LDAPModel> result;

    private String error.
}
```

Modify your builder and instead of setting a string using ldapModel.toString(), provide the list itself.

Currently, your LookupResponseResultList class is having a string representation of List. Provide the list instead of string.